# Is Git merge information per-file or per-directory?

Tags: git

In Perforce, merge information (e.g. merge history) is per-file.
In Subversion, merge information is per-directory.
In Git, is merge information per-file or per-directory?

Comment: What do you mean? What information? Both?

Comment: The Git history is generally based on the entire repository/project.  That is, a given commit or merge in Git represents a snapshot of the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

It's neither.

Subversion is a little peculiar here, because it's built atop a system that deals fundamentally with *directories*.  This means you can, using Subversion, check out one particular directory—well, sort of: you get its subdirectories too.  But it starts with a directory: hence the directory-level merge information.

Git's fundamental unit is neither file nor directory, but rather the *commit*.  You cannot get less than a whole commit.<sup>1</sup>  When you run `git checkout commit-specifier`, Git copies the *entire committed tree* into your index / staging-area—this takes relatively little space; see footnote 1—then copies all of those files from the index to your *work-tree* where you can work on them.

Each Git commit is a full and complete snapshot of *all* of the files in your project, or more precisely, all of the files that you had in your index when you made the commit.  Since the index starts out with all the files from the current commit, it continues to have all of the files in the next commit too.  A merge commit is no different here than any other commit: it has all of the files, in their full and complete glory, but compressed and frozen and Git-ified, the way all files in any commit are compressed and frozen and Git-ified.  Since they are frozen—you cannot change *any* part of *any* commit, ever—they get *shared* if they're unchanged, so if you commit a 100 megabyte file ten times, or even a million times, that *file* uses the same amount of disk space as if you committed the 100 megabyte file just once—because, in effect, you *did*.  (Each commit adds a little bit of space atop the file, for the commit's metadata, but if you're familiar with the idea of a *link* on a Unix/Linux system, you can think of each commit as having a hard link to the one underlying file.)

Meanwhile, the fact that the commit *is* a merge is recorded via the *parent* hash ID or IDs stored in each commit.  Each commit remembers the raw hash ID(s)—the true name, as it were—of the commit(s) that comes immediately before this particular commit.  For most commits, there's only one such hash ID, and we wind up with a backwards-looking chain, so that if we start from the *most recent* commit whose hash is some big ugly hash that we'll just call `H`, we can find its parent whose hash we'll call `G`.  We can then use `G` to find the parent of `G`, which we'll call `F`, and then use `F` to find `F`'s parent, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

We merely need to know the answer to the question: *What is the hash ID of the **last** commit in this chain?*  To find that answer, we look up a *branch name* such as `master`.  The *name* contains the *latest* hash ID—that's all!  Everything else comes from the commits.

The only thing special about a merge commit is that it records at least *two* parent hashes:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             M--...
            /
...--J--K--L
```

The merge information lies in the fact that `M` has two parents, `H` and `L`.  From `M` we can either go backwards to `H`, and follow that chain back, or we can go backwards to `L` and follow that chain back.  All three commits—`M`, `H`, and `L`—are full and complete snapshots, so if we want to see how the top chain commit `H` got modified by merging the bottom chain `L` commit into it, we can compare `H` and `M`.  If we want to see how the bottom chain commit `L` got modified by merging the top chain commit `H` into it, we can compare `L` and `M`.  These are the *same* comparisons we do when, for instance, we want to see how `H` got modified: we compare `G` and `H`, which are two snapshots, to see what changed from `G` to `H`.

If we want to see where the two chains first *diverged*, we just need a wider view:

```
...--E---F---G----H
      \            \
       \            M--...
        \          /
         I--J--K--L
```

If `F`'s parent is `E`, and `J`'s parent is `I` whose parent is `E`, then we can see that `E` was the merge base at the time we merged `H` and `L`.  Since all commits are frozen for all time, if `E` was the merge base then, `E` is still the merge base now.

This means that the answer to your question is: **There is no explicit merge information at all.  The fact that there is a merge, and the information needed to repeat the merge, is implied by the commit graph.**  The commit graph is a data structure you (or Git) derive by reading the individual commits.  Since the commit is the fundamental unit, you always have a whole commit.<sup>2</sup>  In a *shallow* clone, you are allowed to be missing *earlier* commits, but you can fill those in by going back to wherever you cloned-from and "unshallowing" your clone (or just deepening it far enough to see what you need to see).

---

<sup>1</sup>Git does support the concept of *sparse checkout*, but you still get the whole commit.  *All* of its files are still copied into your index.  The sparse checkout merely limits which of those files are then copied from the index to your work-tree.  Since the index copies are mostly-frozen and can directly share the in-commit copies, this reduces the amount of disk space needed, as some files never need to be de-compressed out of their frozen in-commit form.  The next commit you make, if you do make another one, is made from what's in the index, not from what's in the work-tree, so the new commit continues to have *all* of the files, despite the sparse checkout.

<sup>2</sup>Git is adding the idea of allowing a sort of placeholder, in the form of *promisor packs*, where you can have a commit but lack some of its internal data.  That is, the commit itself will still be the fundamental unit, but while you'll know that commit *C* has tree *T*, you might lack the object *T* itself until something explicitly asks for it, and at that point Git would attempt to fulfill the promise by phoning home to whoever made the promise.  This isn't actually in Git yet, but it's slowly making its way into the code base.

Note that this is somewhat similar to shallow clones.  In the case of a shallow clone, you know that commit *C* has parent *P*, but you lack the object *P* due to having a shallow-graft that makes some parts of Git pretend *C* has no parents at all.  Using `git fetch --deepen=number`, you can have Git obtain *P*, but perhaps shallow-graft some grandparent of *P*.  This just replaces the shallow-graft-point with a new one for that grandparent, or removes the shallow graft entirely if you've obtained all parents, e.g., via `git fetch --unshallow`.